# MongoDB - Move embedded array element from one document to another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am a Mongodb beginner. I have a collection where I want to find and pull an item from one document and push it to another matched document in the same collection.

Given: Move the item with `orderNumber: 100` and `itemId: I000007` to `orderNumber: 102` items array

Below is the orders collection.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61264e2dc0e8b5b3daa16c9a"),
    "orderNumber" : "100",
    "__v" : 0,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000005",
            "region" : [ 
                "US", 
                "EUROPE"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000006",
            "region" : []
        }, 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000007",
            "region" : [
                "JAPAN"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61268283c0e8b5b3daa1f245"),
    "orderNumber" : "101",
    "__v" : 0,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000008",
            "region" : []
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61268283c0e8b5b3daa1fg3c"),
    "orderNumber" : "102",
    "__v" : 0,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000009",
            "region" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

After performing the query, I want the below result.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61264e2dc0e8b5b3daa16c9a"),
    "orderNumber" : "100",
    "__v" : 0,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000005",
            "region" : [ 
                "AMRS", 
                "APAC"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000006",
            "region" : []
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61268283c0e8b5b3daa1f245"),
    "orderNumber" : "101",
    "__v" : 0,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : "I000008",
            "region" : []
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61268283c0e8b5b3daa1fg3c"),
    "orderNumber" : "102",
    "__v" : 0,
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId" : "I000009",
            "region" : [],
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "I000007",
            "region" : [
                "JAPAN"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two queries to perform your operation,

**0)** Pre required things:

```
let pullOrderNumber = "100";
let itemId = "I000007";
let pushOrderNumber = "102";
```

**1)** pull the item from `items` array using condition:

- the query will do the operation but will return an old document because we have used `findOneAndUpdate` method, and we need that item to push in another document

```
let oldDoc = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { orderNumber: pullOrderNumber },
  {
    $pull: {
      items: { itemId: itemId }
    }
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/muDUcHBf-PL)

**2)** Filter and find the removed item object from the above result document

```
let pushItem = oldDoc.items.find(i => i.itemId == itemId);
```

**3)** Push an above pulled item into another document

```
await Model.updateOne(
  { orderNumber: pushOrderNumber },
  {
    $push: {
      items: pushItem
    }
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KEdaxZLR__T)